# How to create a combobox into a dgv using entity framework and linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, datagridview

I have an entity Framework Model that I bind to a DGV

```
Dim a as New Model
dim b = from Entry in a.Entries
where Entry.person.windowsusername = SystemInformation.Username.Tostring
Select Entry.Date,
Entry.Begin,
Entry.End,
Entry.Projekt.Projekt_Name

DatagridView1.Datasource = b.tolist
```

`Projekt_Name` comes from another Table and I want to offer the user to select the project. I need a combobox for that but dont know how I can implement that in the code above. I know how to bind linq query results to a combobox since you can find that as a msdn example but cannot find a vb example for the problem above.

Comment: what is the source for the combo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exact code but should give you an idea. 
it's my code to add a combo to a DataGridView and obtain the selected item. It will require some changes for you.

```
    Private m_ObjectTemplateColumnAdded As Boolean = False

'Add the combo to the grid
    Private Sub AddObjectTemplateColumn()
        If m_ObjectTemplateColumnAdded Then Exit Sub
        Dim comboBoxColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        comboBoxColumn.Name = "Combo box column name"
        comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "Name"
        comboBoxColumn.DataSource = ' Add you combo source here !!!!
        comboBoxColumn.Width = 150
        DatagridView1.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn)
        m_ObjectTemplateColumnAdded = True
    End Sub

'ignore grid errors
    Private Sub DatagridView1_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.DataError
        e.ThrowException = False
    End Sub

'hook to the combo
    Private Sub DatagridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DatagridView1.EditingControlShowing

        Dim combo As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then

            ' Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
            ' adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused. 
            RemoveHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)

            ' Add the event handler.  
            AddHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)

        End If

    End Sub

' Get the selected item from the combo
    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim selectedItem As Object =CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedItem
        If selectedItemIs Nothing Then Exit Sub
        'do some thing with selectedItem
    End Sub
```